# Passing a variable that contains While loop as a JSON in a PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to pass `$html` but I have to break it with `;` before While loop. In other words I can't continue `.$html` inside While loop. I want to use this variable as a JSON:

```
$ValueArray=array($html);
echo json_encode ($ValueArray);
```

My code is:

```
$html=""
.$html="                                                               
 <div  class='block_content'>
    <div class='cart_block_list'>
    <dl class='products'>  " 

  while($products1_sc=mysql_fetch_array($products_sc))  
     $rows[]= $products1_sc ;
     foreach ($rows as $row)
     {          
      .$html= "

        <dt id='products". $rowa['id']."' class='first_item'>
        <a class='cart-images' href='http://prol5675.html'>
        <img src='images/".$row['name'].".jpg' ></a>"
                          ...
      }
```

Comment: do ; after $html @j.kh. otherwise your execution will be break or user only while loop can do your stuff only while loop

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements, it really isn't hard.

Comment: So, theoretically, what would the desired output past this point be? After the while loop has completed, what do you want $html to contain? You say that you want to use this variable as a JSON object, but at the moment you're just giving it as a string and giving absolutely no structure to it.